# Mongodb and 'archived' documents

Tags: mongodb

Say we have a mongo collection of PurchaseOrders, for a very busy store.
We have dilemma regarding whether/how to archive old PurchaseOrders.

On the one hand, we're considering to remove old PurchaseOrders (say over 12 months old) from the 'main' collection to another collection. That's because users rarely request them, so it's a shame that they would slow down the main functionality, replication etc.

On the other hand, this complicates our code, because on those rare cases where users do request old data - they expect the same logical behavior as with new data. So we'd get dozens of methods such as 'issueInvioce', 're-add to cart' etc... all becoming more complicated due to having to perform 2-phase searches (and answering the obvious question: **some of the complexity** can be elegantly hidden away in some commonly-used DAO, but not all of it).

Has anyone else faced this problem? Found any tricks or 3rd party tools over mongo that would help with this? Because I guess archiving is quite a common requirement when dealing with large amounts of data. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid complexity, have you condsidered moving the documents, and then inserting them back as needed...  Eg. When an end user requests an archived record, you could reconstitute the documents, and set a new TTL.  From an end user standpoint it's fairly common to have a separate process to follow when needing access to really old data.  Or this could be done behind the scenes if disired.

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks :) it doesn't solve all scenarios (especially searches/reports that don't target a single document). But for some cases it could fit nicely - i really appreciate the idea.